# VSTO: Really password-protect & hide MS Excel Worksheets

Tags: visual-studio, vsto

Is it possible to do the following two things with VSTO VB:

- **HIDING SHEETS:** Prevent users from un-hiding worksheets that they are not meant to. The xlVeryHidden works great but it's almost easily overridden by using another workbook and writing a simple VBA macro to loop through and unhide them all. What is the best way to combat hidden sheets not been shown unless done by the VSTO VB code?
- **PASSWORD PROTECTING SHEETS:** What is the best way to password-protect Excel worksheets in a VSTO VB project? Does VSTO offer any better method than VBA; which is a simple password-protection where the password is saved in an easily accessible XML document? Essentially, I've locked the worksheets only allowing certain ranges to be edited by the end users and they shouldn't be able to edit them.

I am using Visual Studio 2012, working on a MS Office 2013 Excel Workbook at a document-level.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property [Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.visible%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to [XlSheetVisibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlsheetvisibility.aspx).xlSheetVeryHidden in order to hide the worksheet. Your probably could try to disable macro by via [Application.AutomationSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.automationsecurity%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property then set it to `msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable` to disable macro.

There's a nice and neat [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x0th45dh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) about how to programmatically hide Excel worksheet. Please don't forget to take a look at it.

You can set your password to password-protect worksheets via [Workbook.SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214129.aspx) method.  Also, if you'd like to check if workbook is password protected via [Workbook.HasPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.haspassword%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property. Also you can find this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dkcs53f3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) about how to protect worksheets.